# How to design a transfer function for a Model Rocket?

Tags: control-engineering, pid-control, rocketry

I am building a roll stabilized model rocket. I am beginner at controls systems. How do I find out the transfer function of the rocket. Although, I am aware of definitions and stuff of control systems. I just a need a nudge in the right direction.

Also what your thought on using State Space Analysis?

Thanks so much! :D

Comment: What type of research have you done? Can you please update the post with this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Define your inputs (i.e., control surfaces on the fins, steerable motors, etc.)
- Define your output (roll position of the rocket)
- Find the differential equation that describes the roll in terms of the input.
- Linearize (note that if you're using fins then the linearized equation will be dependent on airspeed, and that if you're using steerable motors then the linearized equation will be dependent on thrust -- this will complicate your life, but get over the first hurdle first!)
- Extract the transfer function

State space is not a bad way to go, but if you're only concerned with roll control, and if you're confident that you're not going to be affecting the behavior in yaw or pitch, then this is a classic single-input, single-output system that can be handled with transfer functions.

Comment: hey, thanks for that! It would be awesome if you can link some example! thanks :D

Comment: I just outlined the general procedure for designing a transfer function for a <something>, with customization for what I know about rockets.